# String Replace "\\\" with "\"

Tags: c#, replace

I have a string that contains sequence of three "\" and I have to replace them with single "\".

the string is:

```
string sample = "<ArrayOfMyObject xmlns:i=\\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\\\"";
```

I have tried, as suggested in other threads, with the following code but it did not work:

```
string result = sample.Replace(@"\\\",@"\");
string result = sample.Replace("\\\\\\","\\");
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Your example string doesn't contain three consecutive \\\ because it is not escaped. It does contain `\"` though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace `\\\` with `\` in a `c#` string try this code (tested and working)

```
 string strRegex = @"(\\){3}";
 string strTargetString = @"sett\\\abc";
 var test=Regex.Replace(strTargetString, strRegex, @"\"); //test becomes sett\abc
```

in debug you will see `test=sett\\abc` (2 backslashes but one is an escape).
Don't worry and go to text Visualizer and you'll see the correct value

[image]

then

[image]

in your specific case the code will be

```
 string sample = @"<ArrayOfMyObject xmlns:i=\\\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\\\"";
var result=Regex.Replace(sample , strRegex, @"\");
```

Comment: thanks so much you're solution is elegant. What confuses me was that the debug show the code already with escape .

Answer (score 3):

In your sample, your string doesn't actually have three "\" characters in it - Some of them are escape characters.

\ will actually correspond to a single \ character.
\" will actually correspond to a single " character.

The *value* of your string, in memory, is:-

```
<ArrayOfMyObject xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
```

So, your replace operations do nothing because they do not match anything.

Comment: You're right the string in memory is correct but with debug I saw it whith three "\". Thanks so much!!!!

Answer (score 0):

the output of both of the replaces is

```
<ArrayOfMyObject xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"
```

this looks correct

but maybe you have to add 6 instead of 3 '\' in your input, because there caracters are escape characters.